# Debugging web app on the palm pre?

Tags: debugging, web-applications, browser, palm-pre

I have a web app that works fine on desktop browsers, but struggles on the palm pre browser (via the emulator). How do I debug the app on the palm pre browser? There doesn't seem to be any error console, dom inspector, etc... I'd expect such tools from a web-app oriented phone.

Comment: Some more specifics on what exactly doesnt work would be helpful.  Javascript slow?  CSS not styling as expected, page loads slowly ... ?

Answer (score 0):

The debugging tools on the webOS platform are generally still poor, and thats speaking for the application development.

I dont think there is any debugger for the web browser.  You're stuck with document.write and related.

And for applications themselves, its better, but not by much.  There is a command line debugger that you can use to set break points and inspect.  There is also an inspector based on Safari that you can use to inspect the dom and such.  And there is basic info/warn/error debugging to syslog.  But these are for applications using the Mojo framework, and not exposed to web pages.

That said, the browser is based on Webkit, so its fairly close to Safari 4.  There are some good sized chunks missing in Canvas and advanced CSS support.  Browsing the [developer forums](http://developer.palm.com/distribution/index.php) will help see what CSS and Canvas features are missing or broken.